# Module of the Headers Class/Javascript/

Tags: javascript, api

I'm not a technical person, so I can't code or anything, but I have to incorporate this API into google sheets.

Therefore I use this Javascript Code Sample in google Appscript. But There is no definition of the Headers.

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("x-access-token", "<my gold api key>");
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: myHeaders,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://www.goldapi.io/api/XAU/EUR", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Can somebody tell me where I can find the Modul of the Headers Class and install it? Or is there another way to incorporate this API into google sheets?

Thank you for your Help!

Answer (score 0):

Add these two lines at the top:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const { Headers } = fetch;
```

This is for Node-js. In a browser context your code would work without this, as the `fetch` API is included out of the box, and also `Headers` is defined.